# Ошибка с бд sqlite3 на discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

помогите пожалуйста исправить эту ошибку:

```py
  File "<string>", line 35, in on_ready
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error
```

Вот код:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    name TEXT,
    id INT,
    cash BIGINT,
    rep INT,
    lvl INT
    )""")
    
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass
    connection.commit()

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
                if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
                    connection.commit()
                else:
                    pass
```

вот 35 строка:

```py
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993899/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-s-syntax-error

Comment: Спасибо за помощь